# MVC: 404 not found in ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am showing a number of flights in a view. I have created a button for every flight. On clicking this button I am getting the details of a single flight shown in the view.
here is my view code:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <div class="toFrom">
                            <h3 id="FCity_@item.FlightID">@item.FromCity </h3>
                            <span><i class="fa mx-4 fa-plane"></i></span>
                            <h3 id="TCity_@item.FlightID">@item.ToCity</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="info d-flex">
                            <p class="me-2 " id="DDate_@item.FlightID">@item.DepartureDate.ToShortDateString()</p>
                            <p class="me-2" id="DTime_@item.FlightID">@item.DepartureTime.ToShortTimeString()</p>
                            <p class="me-2 " id="ATime_@item.FlightID">@item.ArrivalTime.ToShortTimeString()</p>

                            <select id="CFare_@item.Fare" class="form-control me-2">

                                @foreach (var re in ddlcabin)
                                {
                                    <option value="@re.Fare">@re.CabinName (@re.Fare)</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                            <button class="form-control btn btn-primary" onclick="Save(@item.FlightID,@item.Fare)">select </button>
                            
                        </div>
                    
                    }
```

Now I want to get these values using and pass them to an action method without using a form in the view.
here is my js code:

```
    function Save(id, fare) {
            var fct = $("#FCity_" + id).text();
            var tct = $("#TCity_" + id).text();
            var ddt = $("#DDate_" + id).text();
            var dt = $("#DTime_" + id).text();
            var at = $("#ATime_" + id).text();
            var cf = $("#CFare_" + fare).val();
            
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'Flights/ReserveFlight',
                data: { FromCity: fct, ToCity: tct, DepDate: ddt, DepTime: dt, ArrTime: at, CabinFare: cf },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("data is inserted")
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            });
}
```

when I click the save button it shows an error in the browser console and doesn't hit the debugger applied to the action method

here is my action method:

```
public ActionResult ReserveFlight(string FromCity, string ToCity, DateTime DepDate, DateTime DepTime, DateTime ArrTime, int CabinFare)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

here is the error:

> GET
> http://localhost:64480/Flights/Flights/ReserveFlight?FromCity=Islamabd%20&ToCity=Karachi&DepDate=5%2F20%2F2022&DepTime=8%3A30%20AM&ArrTime=12%3A00%20AM&CabinFare=4500 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the URL in ajax as:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/Flights/ReserveFlight',
    data: { FromCity: fct, ToCity: tct, DepDate: ddt, DepTime: dt, ArrTime: at, CabinFare: cf },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("data is inserted")
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Or work with `UrlHelper`.

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("Flights", "ReserveFlight")',
    data: { FromCity: fct, ToCity: tct, DepDate: ddt, DepTime: dt, ArrTime: at, CabinFare: cf },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log("data is inserted")
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
});
```

Reference: [Action(String, String) | UriHelper.Action() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string))

Comment: thanks a lot. Now it's working fine